# Looking for the BiqQuery equivalent of LATERAL JOIN in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, lateral-join

While composing a query in BiqQuery I realized that BiqQuery does not support/implement LATERAL joins. I was wondering if there is an equivalent function that I am missing.

Here is my intended code:

```
SELECT
  'Bestand (#)' AS label,
  'maand' AS level,
  a.dim1,
  a.dim2,
  'Vorig jaar' AS dim3,
  b.count AS measure,
  lag(b.count, 12) OVER (ORDER BY a.dim1, a.dim2) AS benchmark
FROM (
  SELECT
    k.jaar AS dim1,
    k.maand AS dim2,
    CAST(CONCAT(k.jaar, '-', FORMAT("%02d", k.maand), '-01') AS date) AS start_of_month,
    DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(CAST(CONCAT(k.jaar, '-', FORMAT("%02d", k.maand), '-01') AS date), INTERVAL 1 month), INTERVAL 1 day) AS end_of_month
    FROM `dev.kalender` k
    GROUP BY k.jaar, k.maand
    ORDER BY k.jaar, k.maand
    ) a,
LATERAL (
    SELECT
      COUNT(p.value.int_value) AS sessions,
    FROM
      `analytics_229730901.events_*`,
      UNNEST(event_params) AS p
    WHERE
      event_name = 'session_start'
      AND event_date BETWEEN a.start_of_month AND a.end_of_month
      AND p.key = 'ga_session_id'
      AND platform IN ('IOS', 'ANDROID')
      AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20201205' AND '20220101'
  ) b
```

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Standard PostgreSQL *does* support lateral joins. You shouldn't mix up standard SQL with BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @LaurenzAlbe, I altered my question accordingly